# SetAllProperties method missing in structuremap Registry

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a fairly old project that needs some work doing on it, i have run update-package in nuget and now get the following in my TypeRegistry

> The name 'SetAllProperties' does not exist in the current scope

The TypeRegistry is as follows

```
public class TypeRegistry : Registry
    {
    public TypeRegistry()
        {
        For<ILogger>().Singleton().Use<Log4NetLogger>();
        this.SetAllProperties(p => p.OfType<ILogger>());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case and point me to anything that could help me to resolve this problem please.

Comment: Focus on "current scope".  If the scope contains another interface or class named "Registry" then you will get this compile error.  Try typing the full name instead, StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. I think this method might have been deprecated in newer versions. I was able to accomplish setter injection using the `Policies` property of the Registry Class.

```
public class TypeRegistry : Registry
{
    public TypeRegistry()
    {
        For<ILogger>().Singleton().Use<Log4NetLogger>();
        Policies.FillAllPropertiesOfType<ILogger>().Use<Log4NetLogger>();
    }
}
```

Edit:

Just found the SetAllProperties method on Policies as well. I believe either one will inject the property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.Policies.SetAllProperties(
        policy => policy.WithAnyTypeFromNamespace("StructureMap.Testing.Widget3"));
});
```

See the official documentation here http://structuremap.github.io/setter-injection/